# Font Awesome in Markers of Google Map (ANDROID)

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, customization

I have a mapm and I want to use font-awesome to customize my markers and my Actual location like this

[image: MARKERS WITH FONT AWESOME]

Please, help me!

Comment: First, what exactly in your image is from Font Awesome? Second, please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: Markers and the circle (Your current Position). And honestly I don't have code in this moment because I don't know how can Do that